# Call to undefined method error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following function:

```
public function addSubject(Request $request) {
    $student=User::find($request->invisible);
    $classsubjects = $request['classsubjects'];
    $student->classSubjects()->attach($cclasssubjects);
}
```

This gives me an error saying:

> BadMethodCallException
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

Comment: Please share `classSubjects()` definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function classSubjects() in your Package model has to return a BelongsToMany relationship in order to use attach().

```
public function classSubjects() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('classSubjects');
}
```